# Ionic3-Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

How to solve these issue `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'.` in ionic3

Here I added code

```
adduser(newuser) {
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.afireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newuser.email, 
newuser.password).then(() => {
    this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName: newuser.displayName,
      photoURL: ''
    }).then(() => {
      this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid)({
        uid: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid,
        displayName: newuser.displayName,
        photoURL: 'give a dummy placeholder url here'
      }).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
        }).catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
      })
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    reject(err);
  })
})
return promise;
}
```

I dont know how to solve issue??

When I Run `ionic serve` it works fine

But when I run `ionic cordova run android` it shows the following issue `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'.`

Comment: Have any idea?@Utpaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issues by adding push() and set method

Comment: that's great @vignesh

Answer (score 0):

Promise-like objects (thenables) may not have `catch` method, this is what the error says about. They need to be converted to promises with `Promise.resolve` in order to be used as usual promises. Notice that `catch` is syntactic sugar for second `then` argument, and thenables can be used with `then` alone, although method result still should be converted to a promise.

The code uses promise construction antipattern. Once there's a promise, there is no need to use `new Promise`:

```
adduser(newuser) {
  returnPromise.resolve(this.afireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newuser.email, 
newuser.password)).then(() => { return Promise.resolve(...) });
}
```

This works even better with `async..await` because it naturally converts results to promises:

```
async adduser(newuser) {
  await this.afireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newuser.email, 
newuser.password);
  await this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile(...);
  await this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid).set(...);
  return { success: true };
}
```

Comment: im new to use this...I dont know how use this?

Comment: `async` function is supposed to be used as provided. Some method arguments were replaced with ... for readability.